# How to make thumbnail text float right on small viewport on bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is how the standard thumbnail looks like 
[image]

When the sm viewport is reached I need it to look like this: 
[image]

as you can see on this jsfiddle Bootstrap only shrinks the container by default
http://jsfiddle.net/32o4kses/

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img data-src="holder.js/100%x200" alt="100%x200" style="height: 200px; width: 100%; display: block;" src="http://placehold.it/241x200" data-holder-rendered="true">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3 id="thumbnail-label">Thumbnail label<a class="anchorjs-link" href="#thumbnail-label"><span class="anchorjs-icon"></span></a></h3>
        <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img data-src="holder.js/100%x200" alt="100%x200" style="height: 200px; width: 100%; display: block;" src="http://placehold.it/241x200" data-holder-rendered="true">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3 id="thumbnail-label">Thumbnail label<a class="anchorjs-link" href="#thumbnail-label"><span class="anchorjs-icon"></span></a></h3>
        <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img data-src="holder.js/100%x200" alt="100%x200" style="height: 200px; width: 100%; display: block;" src="http://placehold.it/241x200" data-holder-rendered="true">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3 id="thumbnail-label">Thumbnail label<a class="anchorjs-link" href="#thumbnail-label"><span class="anchorjs-icon"></span></a></h3>
        <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Bootstrap grid inside each `thumbnail` like this..

```
        <div class="thumbnail row">
          <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
          <img data-src="holder.js/100%x200" alt="100%x200" style="height: 200px; width: 100%; display: block;" src="http://placehold.it/241x200" data-holder-rendered="true">
          </div>
          <div class="caption col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <h3 id="thumbnail-label">Thumbnail label<a class="anchorjs-link" href="#thumbnail-label"><span class="anchorjs-icon"></span></a></h3>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
            <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
```

http://codeply.com/go/L1m3V7mvHb